how to select all campaigns except ( already liked )
how to select all campaigns except ( already liked ) using codeigniter v3
Tables :
campaigns   (id, user_id, post_id, post_url, quantity, status)
liked_posts (id, user_id, post_id, status)
the expected sql query
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
`campaigns` 
WHERE post_id NOT IN 
(SELECT 
post_id 
FROM 
`liked_posts` 
WHERE user_id like '-NgAN8gGt-9Kna5QKJvJ' 
AND status = 1)

my code ( not working + have 2 separate  queries )


$_client = $params['client'] ;
$already_liked = $this->model->get (" GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('''', post_id, '''' )) as liked", $this->tb_liked_posts,  ['user_id'=> $_client->user_id,'status'=>'1' ]);
if( $already_liked->liked ){
    $already_liked_list = $already_liked->liked;
}else{
    $already_liked_list = '' ;
}

$already_liked = explode(",",$already_liked_list) ; 

$this->db->select(self::entity_fields['campaigns']);
$this->db->select('u.*');
$this->db->from($this->tb_campaigns . ' cmp');
$this->db->join($this->tb_users." u", "u.user_id = cmp.user_id", 'left');

$this->db->where_not_in('cmp.post_id', $already_liked );
$query = $this->db->get();
$campaign_list = $query->result();



what is the question then since you provided a query?

Your query selects all campaigns except the ones that have been liked by that user. Did you mean to select campaigns by that user except the ones that are liked by anyone?

@cute_programmer , how to build this query using codeigniter v3 ?

@Barmar , i need to select all campaigns except the ones that have been liked by that user , example: `users (id,username,email,status)
44,instagram,help@instagram.com,active
campaigns
1,44,'fqzglkfbg','https://...',5000,'pending'
2,45,'tyjdtyjjy','https://...',2000,'pending'
3,46,'ryjtyrdjd','https://...',7000,'pending'
4,47,'oihmxbtde','https://...',4000,'pending'
liked_posts (id, user_id, post_id, status)
1,44,'oihmxbtde',1
i nedd only campain id 2and 3 ( campaign id 4 is already liked and 1 its his owner ) `

The query looks correct, you're just asking how to translate it to CI syntax?

@Barmar yes sir
